# I'm using a Dell G5 15SE 5505 with Ryzen 7 CPU and Radeon RX 5600M graphics processor

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot, bios

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer using a bootable USB stick. I'm using Rufus to install the Linux ISO with a MBR partition scheme with target system of BIOS or UEFI and a FAT32 File System. When I try to boot Ubuntu via the USB stick in the BIOS (v 1.4.4) and select the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option this error screen pops up, and after a few seconds it reboots Windows and shows the normal login screen. I disabled Secure Boot, but it doesn't seem to work.

The error that pops on the screen is the following:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (Bug): Could not resolve symbol ... AE_NOT_FOUND,   
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog  
AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
~
```

[image]

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to install such an old version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I need to work with a version of ROS that is only available under the 18.04.5 Ubuntu distribution.